# RxJava 2 mock Observable doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I use RxJava 2 `Observable` to wrap barcode scanner in one of my app. This snippet show how I subscribe to `Observable` and listen to it's events

```
override fun start() {
    disposables.addAll(subscribeToBarcodeReader(), loadUser())
}

private fun subscribeToBarcodeReader(): Disposable {
    return barcodeObservable
        .subscribeOn(bgScheduler)
        .observeOn(mainScheduler)
        .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { barcode -> saveBarcode(barcode) },
                onComplete = { Log.d(TAG, "Barcode observable complete") },
                onError = { e -> Log.d(TAG, "Barcode observable error", e) }
        )
}
```

`barcodeObservable` is object of `Observable<Barcode>` type. This all works fine on real device with real barcode scanner. Now I want to unit test the `saveBarcode()` method and try to mock the `Observable<Barcode>` this way

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class OrbFoldersPresenterTests {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var jobService: FolderJobService
    private val bgScheduler = TestScheduler()
    private val mainScheduler = TestScheduler()
    private val barcodeObservable: Observable<Barcode> = Observable.just(Barcode(
            "2500020109205", LocalDateTime.now().toString()))
    @Mock
    private lateinit var userStore: UserStore
    @Mock
    private lateinit var prefs: Preferences
    @Mock
    private lateinit var barcodeService: BarcodeReadService

    @Test
    fun testBarcodeSave() {
        val jobId = 201804040001
        val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

        whenever(userStore.authorizedUser()).thenReturn(Maybe.just(User()))

        val presenter = OrbFoldersPresenter(jobId, jobService, disposables, bgScheduler,
                mainScheduler, barcodeObservable, userStore, prefs, barcodeService)
        presenter.start()
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that when I call `presenter.start()` presenter must subscribe to `barcodeObservable` and receive `onNext()` event with object I've provided. But this isn't happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TestScheduler` is useful if you need to test timing with your streams. Since your only concern with your implementation should be to run the stream synchronously, you should better use a `Schedulers.trampoline()` instead. This will then call subscription and observation without a thread change.

Answer (score 1):

There's asynchronous processing going on because of subscribing and observing on given schedulers. `onNext()` does not get invoked synchronously as expected by your test code.

With a `TestScheduler`, you can e.g. call `triggerActions()` or `advanceTimeBy()` to execute asynchronous code.